# Spreading getElementsByClassName or querySelectorAll gives an error in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, spread

I'm converting a list of DOM nodes to an array using the following code:

```
const elements = [...document.getElementsByClassName(selector)];
```

But with TypeScript I'm getting error like: `Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>' is not an array type or does not have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

I'm not sure what should I do in such case. I tried to type it like:

```
const elements: HTMLElement[] = [...document.getElementsByClassName(selector)];
```

But it doesn't work.

This is my TypeScript config file (`tsconfig.json`):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "umd",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me on TS 3.5.2 (I see the iterator definition in `lib.dom.iterable.d.ts`), HTMLCollections in modern browsers do have iterators

Comment: I'm using TypeScript 3.5.2 and it's yelling. Maybe it's a configuration issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default Typescript will use .slice by default.

You should add the flag --downlevelIteration for it to work for all iterators, including html collections.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

You should have dom.iterable as a lib for it to work. You currently have no lib specified, so a default is used according to your target, that's why it's not working.

Comment: Please, see updated description of the issue. I've added my config. As you can see, the flag is set to true.

Comment: I edited my answer, it should work if you add the correct libs